# Word embedding with gensim and FastText, training on pretrained vectors

Tags: python, gensim, word-embedding, fasttext

I am trying to load the pretrained vec file of Facebook fasttext crawl-300d-2M.vec with the next code:

```
from gensim.models.fasttext import load_facebook_model, load_facebook_vectors

model_facebook = load_facebook_vectors('fasttext/crawl-300d-2M.vec')
```

But it fails with the next error:

```
NotImplementedError: Supervised fastText models are not supported
```

It is not possible to load this vector?

If it is possible, afterwards can I train it with my own sentences?

Thanks in advance.

Whole error trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-181-f8262e0857b8> in <module>
----> 1 model_facebook = load_facebook_vectors('fasttext/crawl-300d-2M.vec')

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/fasttext.py in load_facebook_vectors(path, encoding)
   1196 
   1197     """
-> 1198     model_wrapper = _load_fasttext_format(path, encoding=encoding, full_model=False)
   1199     return model_wrapper.wv
   1200 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/fasttext.py in _load_fasttext_format(model_file, encoding, full_model)
   1220     """
   1221     with gensim.utils.open(model_file, 'rb') as fin:
-> 1222         m = gensim.models._fasttext_bin.load(fin, encoding=encoding, full_model=full_model)
   1223 
   1224     model = FastText(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/_fasttext_bin.py in load(fin, encoding, full_model)
    339         model.update(dim=magic, ws=version)
    340 
--> 341     raw_vocab, vocab_size, nwords, ntokens = _load_vocab(fin, new_format, encoding=encoding)
    342     model.update(raw_vocab=raw_vocab, vocab_size=vocab_size, nwords=nwords, ntokens=ntokens)
    343 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/_fasttext_bin.py in _load_vocab(fin, new_format, encoding)
    192     # Vocab stored by [Dictionary::save](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/src/dictionary.cc)
    193     if nlabels > 0:
--> 194         raise NotImplementedError("Supervised fastText models are not supported")
    195     logger.info("loading %s words for fastText model from %s", vocab_size, fin.name)
    196 

NotImplementedError: Supervised fastText models are not supported
```

Comment: Is that the exact line of code that triggers that error? Can you edit your question to show the full error message & call-stack (with lines-of-involved-code) that's shown?

Comment: Yes, thats the exact line. I'm editing with the whole trace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe, but am not certain, that in this particular case you're getting this error because you're trying to load a set of just-plain vectors (which FastText projects tend to name as files ending `.vec`) with a method that's designed for use on the FastText-specific format that includes subword/model info.

As a result, it's misinterpreting the file's leading bytes as declaring the model as one using FastText's '-supervised' mode. (Gensim truly doesn't support such full models, in that less-common mode. But it could load the end-vectors from such a model, and in any case your file isn't truly from that mode.)

Released files that will work with `load_facebook_vectors()` typically end with `.bin`. See the docs for this method for more details:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.load_facebook_vectors

So, you could either:

- Supply an alternate `.bin`-named, Facebook-FastText-formatted set of vectors (with subword info) to this method. (From a quick look at their download options, I believe their file analogous to your 1st try would  be named `crawl-300d-2M-subword.bin` & be about 7.24GB in size.)
- Load the file you have, with just its full-word vectors, via:

```py
    from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
    model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('fasttext/crawl-300d-2M.vec', binary=False)
```

In this latter case, no FastText-specific features (like the synthesis of guess-vectors for out-of-vocabulary words using subword vectors) will be available - but that info isn't in the 'crawl-300d-2M.vec' file, anyway. (Those features would be available if you used the larger `.bin` file & `.load_facebook_vectors()` method above.)

Comment: Many thanks for your kind explanation, now I have it clearer. I think I will go for the bin file to train it with my own text.

Comment: Alas, I don't think the `.bin` files in Facebook's pretrained releases are the full models that you'd need to continue training – they're still just the (full word & subword) outputs of the model, not its full internal state.

Comment: As I can understand in gensims webpage the bin models are the only ones that let you train the model in new data. Otherwise you can just load the word embedding vectors if you are not intended to continue training the model.

Comment: The docs I can find are clear that `load_facebook_vectors()` returns a set of vectors - which wouldn't allow for continued training. *If* you had a full saved model, that could be loaded by `load_facebook_model()`. (And such a model could receive more training, but expanding its vocabulary is tricky & error-prone.) But `crawl-300d-2M-subword.bin` may not be a full model.